# Display base64 encoded image in FLTK

Tags: c++, image, base64, fltk

Is it possible to display images that have been base64 encoded as strings in FLTK?  I want to avoid having an extra image file outside the executable if possible.  I might be able to package the image with the executable, but it seems easier just to base64 encode it inside the source code.  I might be mistaken, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A long while ago I also tried to embed images to my FLTK app, base64 was the obvious choice, unfortunately I can't recall what prevented me to use it.

So I end up with a [small utility](https://github.com/andreldm/kissplayer/blob/2e6cf65b00003c683e540fa153a73148fdc2713d/img/util/png2img.cpp) which serializes PNG files to Fl_RGB_Image as byte array (this is my tweaked version, I can't remember where I found it, so I can't credit its original author).

Compile it as you would any FLTK app, e.g. `g++ -o "png2img" png2img.cpp -lfltk_images -lfltk -lpng` (or see the Makefile at GitHub), then run it as `./png2img <path to folder with png files>`. It'll generate two files: `images.cpp` and `images.h`, feel free to rename.

Finally you can add `images.cpp` to your build chain and use `images.h`:

```
#include "images.h" // check the available images
// ...
button_play = new Fl_Button();
button_play->image(img_icon_play); // A Fl_RGB_Image from images.h
```